# Get text of selector, put into if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, selector

I'm trying to get the text of this selector (the upload date of a video in the search result):

```
uploadedago: #metadata-line > span:nth-child(4)
```

the text is this: "uploaded x *time* ago". the *x* in that is a number, and *time* is one of these: minutes, minute, seconds, second.

I want the get the text and if *x* is less than 5, then it will add the video link/URL to the database to then comment on. But if the *x* is more than 5, then it will loop refresh the page every 10 seconds until eligible videos are met.

How do I do this? This is the main part of the code that comments:

```
async function startApp(config, browserconfig)
{
   const keyword = config.keywords;
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch(browserconfig);
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.setViewport(
   {
      width: 1366,
      height: 768
   });
   await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() =>
   {
      delete navigator.__proto__.webdriver;
   });

   await page.setUserAgent(randomUserAgent.UA());
   const loadCookies = async (page, filePath) => {
      // Read the cookies from the file
      const cookiesString = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath);
      const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString); // Parse the cookies string into an object
    
      // Set the cookies in the page
      await Promise.all(cookies.map((cookie) => {
        if (typeof cookie.sameSite !== 'string') {
          cookie.sameSite = '';
        }
        return page.setCookie(cookie);
      }));
    };
    
    await loadCookies(page, './cookies1.json');
    
    
    

   await page.goto(
      'https://www.youtube.com', wait)

   console.log('=========== Start Commenting ==============');

   spinners.add('first-spinner',
   {
      text: 'Searching for videos..',
      color: 'yellow',
   });
   for (let i = 0; i < keyword.length; i++)
   {
      if (config.trending == true)
      {
         await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending');
         //await autoscroll._autoScroll(page);
      }
      else
      {
         await page.goto(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${keyword[i]}&sp=CAISBAgBEAE%253D&sp=EgIQAQ%253D%253D`);

         

         const text = await page.$(selector.uploadedago.innerText);
         if (text.match.uploadedago(/uploaded [0-5] minutes ago/))
         {
            await page.evaluate(() =>
            {
               document
                  .querySelector(selector.uploadedago.innerText);
            });
         }
         else{
            wait();
            page.reload();

         }

         const element = await page.$(selector.shortvideos,
         );
         if (element)
         {
            await page.evaluate(() =>
            {
               document
                  .querySelector(selector.shortvideos)
                  .remove();
            });
         }
         //await autoscroll._autoScroll(page);
      }

      await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
      spinners.succeed('first-spinner',
      {
         text: 'done..',
         color: 'green'
      });
      await page.waitForTimeout(7000);
      spinners.add('hasil',
      {
         text: 'Collecting videos..',
         color: 'yellow'
      });
      
      //collecting links
      let linked = await Promise.all((await page.$$(selector.videoTitleinSearch)).map(async a =>
      {
         return {
            url :await (await a.getProperty('href')).jsonValue(),
            title : await (await a.getProperty('title')).jsonValue()
         };
      }));

      let hrefs = await Promise.all((await page.$$(selector.shortsTitleinSearch)).map(async a =>
      {
         return await (await a.getProperty('href')).jsonValue();
      }));

      if (hrefs.length === 0)
      {
         linked.push(hrefs);
      }

      const link = linked.filter((el) => el.url != null);

      spinners.succeed('hasil',
      {
         text: `FOUND ${link.length} LINKS`,
         color: 'green',
      });

      for (i in link)
      {
         if (readLog().includes(link[i]))
         {
            spinners.add('already',
            {
               text: 'already commented on video..',
               color: 'red',
            });
            continue;
         }
         spinners.add('comment',
         {
            text: 'commenting on video..',
            color: 'yellow',
         });
         const tweet = link[i].url;
         const title = link[i].title;
         const pages = await browser.newPage();
         await pages.setViewport(
         {
            width: 1366,
            height: 768
         });
         await pages.setUserAgent(randomUserAgent.UA());


         try
         {
            if (tweet.includes(uploadedago.innerText(/uploaded [0-5] minutes ago/)))
            {
               await pages.goto(tweet);
            }
            if (tweet.includes("shorts"))
            {
               await pages.goto(tweet.replace(/shorts/, "watch"));
            }
            else
            {
               // console.log(tweet);
               await pages.goto(tweet);
            }
            try
            {
               await likeVideos.likeVideos(pages);
            }
            catch (error)
            {
               console.log(error);
            }
            await pages.bringToFront();
            await pages.waitForTimeout(4000);
            await pages.evaluate(() =>
            {
               window.scrollBy(0, 550);
            });

            try
            {
               await pages.waitForSelector(selector.catchErrorInComment,
               {
                  timeout: 4000
               });
               console.log("Can't Comment");

               await pages.close();
            }
            catch
            {
               await pages.waitForSelector(selector.inputComment,
               {
                  timeout: 4000,
               });

               await pages.evaluate(() =>
               {
                  document.querySelector('#simplebox-placeholder').click();
               });
               spinners.update('comment',
               {
                  text: 'collecting comments to copy .. ',
                  color: 'yellow',
               });

               if (config.copycomment && config.ai == false) 
               {
                  await copycommnet.copyComment(pages, spinners, config);
               }else if(config.ai){
                  await aiCommented.createComments(pages , spinners ,title, config)
               }
               else if(!config.copycomment && !config.ai)
               {
                  await manualComment.manualComment(pages, spinners, config);
               }else{
                  console.log(" Check Your Configuration")
               }
               await pages.waitForTimeout(config.delay * 1000);
               await pages.close();
               spinners.succeed('comment',
               {
                  text: 'Success commenting',
                  color: 'green',
               });
               Logger.log('./logs/succesCommenting.log', config.usernamegoogle, tweet, 'success')
            }
         }
         catch (e)
         {
            await pages.close();
      
               Logger.log('./logs/errorCommenting.log', config.usernamegoogle, tweet, 'failed', e)
          
         }
         await wait(config.delay);
      }

      spinners.add('delay',
      {
         text: `wait .. we are delaying for ${config.delaycomment}s`,
         color: 'yellow',
      });
   }
   spinners.add('done',
   {
      text: `COMMENTS ADDED, FINISHING UP ..`,
      color: 'green',
   });

   

   await browser.close();
}

startApp(config, Config(paths,config,executablePath("chrome")));

function readLog()
{
   const data = fs.readFileSync('./logs/succesCommenting.log', 'utf8');
   return data;
}
```

**So if a video uploaded 3 minutes ago, it will get the link to the database, same for any videos that say "seconds/second ago". But if there are no videos like that, then refresh the page until there is, and continue with the commenting.**

I tried the "try" method to loop but doesn't work, and I don't know how to get the inner text of the selector. *the main worry is the loop part*.

*Disclaimer: I'm only using this to comment on my own videos, I'm simply just testing this on other videos so it will work in the final stages on my own channel and videos.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: `document.querySelector("selector").innerText`

Comment: @Barmar looks good, how would I add that to the script, then loop it to get links only of videos with the text saying "uploaded x ago" where x = <5 minutes/seconds?

Comment: You could use a regular expression. `if (text.match(/uploaded [0-5] minutes ago/))`

Comment: Can you add a `data-` attribute to the elements to indicate when they were uploaded? That would make selection easier than picking through their text.

Comment: @Barmar I'm having a hard time adding that to the code. Could you perhaps make an answer showing me what you mean exactly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using, so I don't know how it fits in. I'm not even sure which part of the code is accessing the element whose text you want, is it ```document.querySelector(selector.shortvideos).remove();```?

Comment: No, the shorts part is to replace the "shorts" in the url with "watch?v=".
I've edited the code to show where the method to find the valid videos. (above shorts part)